# Width from background-image in an inline flexbox model

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, viewport-units

Is it possible to calculate the min-width of an element from it's background image using only css?

Within an inline flexbox wrapper taking up a full viewport height, we can use javascript to calculate the relative width of each child div - based on the (w / h) scale of the background image.

```
var scale = ((img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight) * 100);
```

Then applying this to the element using css3 viewport height

```
element.style.minWidth = scale + 'vh';
```

So if an image was `130px width x 100px height`, the min-width applied to the div is `130vh`.

Can a background image width based layout be achieved without javascript?

Fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/ucxyefmL/

Answer (score 0):

To scale the background image to fit inside the div:

background-size: contain;

To scale the background image to cover the whole div:

background-size: cover;

Comment: Hi W3, thanks for your insight. I'm actually trying to figure out how to use the background-image to determine the precise width of an element, so in theory both background-size contain & cover would achieve the same aesthetic.